# Form (Ajax) Post inside KendoUI template

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, kendo-ui

I need to create a Form Post (Ajax) inside KendoUI Template, unfortunately without success.

```
<form id="commentSubmit">
  <div class="form-group">
   <textarea class="form-control k-textbox" name="body" id="bodyComment"></textarea>
   <input type="hidden" name="post_id" id="post_idComment" value="#= id #" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
   <button class="k-button k-primary" type="submit">Add Comment</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

We have a script for the Ajax post with id #commentSubmit but it's not working.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#commentSubmit').submit(function() {
$.ajax({
   url: "url.to.post",
   method: "POST",
   dataType: "json",
   data: {
   "body": $("#bodyComment").val(),
    "post_id" : $("#post_idComment").val()
   },
....
```

We found on internet something like

```
<form action="http://url.to.post" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="POST" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="\#template" id="form0" method="post">
```

But it redirects to the URL and that's something we don't want to.

Any advise please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

1. `id` to `class`:

   ```
   <form class="commentSubmit">
   ```
2. Here too:

   ```
   $(document).on('submit', '.commentSubmit', function() {
   ```
3. Prevent form's submission:

   ```
   $(document).on('submit', '.commentSubmit', function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
   ```

This should make any form's submission added with template with class `commentSubmit` to be intercepted and handled with an ajax request.

Tip: Use jQuery's [`serialize`](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) to get the whole form data:

```
$.ajax({
    data: $(this).serialize() // Being 'this' the form when inside the 'submit' event
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<form method="post" id="commentSubmit" name="commentSubmit" action="#" autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="form-group">
    <textarea class="form-control k-textbox" name="body" id="bodyComment"></textarea>
    <input type="hidden" name="post_id" id="post_idComment" value="#= id #" />
    <button type="submit" class="k-button k-primary" id="btnSubmit" form="commentSubmit">Add Comment</button>
  </div>
</form>                                             

$("#commentSubmit").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: "url.to.post",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            "body": $("#bodyComment").val(),
            "post_id": $("#post_idComment").val()
        }
    });
}
```